# Magento: how to add new input for custom mass action?

Tags: magento, action

My task is updating the attribute of products via custom mass action, which needs to get argument of operation from user.

To do this I added my custom action "Update price" to standard mass action select. As "additional" I used list of operation like "command 1, command 2" and so on. According to logic, after this command is selected I need to show input to get argument for operation from user.

So question is how to add HTML-input just after custom mass action selected?

Thx for replies.

UPD:

In Admin_Block_Template I found

```
public function getButtonHtml($label, $onclick, $class='', $id=null) {
    return $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
        ->setData(array(
            'label'     => $label,
            'onclick'   => $onclick,
            'class'     => $class,
            'type'      => 'button',
            'id'        => $id,
        ))
        ->toHtml();
}
```

I was trying to do similar. I created Block which by toHtml() generates HTML-input, however unclear how to bind this code to mass action's select and make as part of form.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Override some methods in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: do you want like this?   http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/26/admin-part2-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs/